# Wicked gem can't pass place_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

I am using wicked gem in order to make a multi step form. Although I am getting the error Couldn't find Place without an ID when I am trying to hit the continue button in the general step (first step of wicked). My places_controller code is

```
def new
@place = Place.new
respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.json { render json: @place }
end
end

def create
@place = Place.new(params[:place])

respond_to do |format|
  if @place.save
    session[:place_id]=@place.id
    format.html { redirect_to place_steps_path :place_id => @place.id }
    format.json { render json: @place, status: :created, location: @place }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

end
```

My place_steps_controller has

```
class PlaceStepsController < ApplicationController
include Wicked::Wizard
steps :general, :explicit

def show
    @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
    render_wizard
end

def update
    @place = Place.find(params[:place_id])
    @place.update_attributes (params[:place])
    render_wizard @place
end

end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in `PlaceStepsController` you are trying to find Place by the id saved in sessions?

Comment: Yep, I saw that too. Thanks for your response!

Comment: so you fixed that, right?

Comment: if yes it is a good idea to place your answer here and mark it as accepted, so the other who will have the same issue would know what to do. Leaving the question without an answer will help nobody.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and my code looks like yours. Did you find the solution?

Comment: No, I actually dropped the idea of a multi step form.